# firebase storage ERORR

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know what is the problem but the problem is with **StorageTaskSnapsot** and **onComplete**
the error says ***The getter 'onComplete' isn't defined for the type 'StorageUploadTask'***

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  uploadPic() async {
    //String fileName = path.basename(_image1.path);
    StorageReference reference =
        storage.ref().child("image1" + DateTime.now().toString());
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_image1);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    imageUrl1 = url;
    return url;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  uploadPic() async {
    //String fileName = path.basename(_image1.path);
    Reference reference = storage.ref().child("image1" + DateTime.now().toString());
    String url = await reference.putFile(_image1).then((_) => reference.getDownloadURL());
    return url;
  }
```

And this also:

```
   FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  uploadPic() async {
    //String fileName = path.basename(_image1.path);
    Reference reference = storage.ref().child("image1" + DateTime.now().toString());
    try {
      await reference.putFile(_image1);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return reference.getDownloadURL();
  }
```

Comment: it says Undefined class 'Reference'

Comment: What version of the dependency are you using? My response is for  
cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1, syntax was the same also for the last version before null-safety 0.16.0+1

Comment: mine is also  ^1.0.1,

Comment: I apologize, I meant to say  firebase_storage: ^8.0.0, as this is a firebase_storage function, not firestore.